# How to git push without having to pull and without forcing

Tags: git, github, git-push

So, I have two distinct directories, in distinct places in my computer (they have nothing to with  each other). So, I'd like to push both of them to the same repository in github, but without having to mess their content locally.
That means that I can't use `git push -f` in one of the directories, otherwise the contet of the other gets removed from github repository.
What approach do you guys suggest?

Comment: What _possible_ reason can you have for pushing to completely unrelated repositories to the same GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to add and commit those directories.

You could create two branches and afterwards merge them. There shouldn't be any conflicts this way.

```
$ cd <folder-A>
$ git push <remote> <branch-A>
$ cd <folder-B>
$ git push <remote> <branch-B>
$ git fetch <remote>
$ git merge <remote>/<branch-A>
```

Comment: That won't work, because, as I said, the local directories have distinct content. So, if the only way to push from branch B, after having pushed from A, is to force the push, which would remove the content of A from the repository.